# MATLAB:How to retrieve a value from excel to MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

For example, if an excel file contains numerical values with decimal places within first 2 rows and first 2 columns.
I want import a value that is in 2nd row and in 1st column.

How to import that specific value from excel file to MATLAB and use the value for computation? Any example?

Comment: There are plenty of examples [in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/spreadsheets.html)...

Answer (score 0):

With some googling you can easily find this example [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthf_dr) on the matlab documentation. You read in the file with the function xlsread  and then access the appropriate element.

```
A = xlsread('myfile.xls');
D = A(1,2);
```